# Why cant read property 'style' of null in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I keep getting stuck on this javascript error!
All I want to do is edit two values for CSS properties when a button is clicked.
I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

It occurs on the first document.getElementById line (below).

I've added the JavaScript in the footer of the page, but have also trialed in other positions, so don't know why it can't pick up the element.

HTML:

```
<a id="loadForm" href="">LINK</a>
<div id="FormContainer">
    <!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#loadForm').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('#FormContainer').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('#FormContainer').style.visability = 'visible';  
    })
});
```

Comment: The # selector prefix is for jQuery not getElementById() .. why are you using getElementById? - $('#FormContainer').hide()/show()

Comment: Why the odd mix of jquery and not jquery?

Comment: Also it's `visibility` and not `visability`.

Comment: You have a `#` in your `getElementById()` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Very confused why you switch from `$(...)` to `jQuery('#loadForm')`.  They're the same thing, you should pick one and stick to it.

Comment: @meagar no, they are not the same.

Comment: @canon Yes, they are. `$` and `jQuery` (assuming you haven't included something else which also uses `$`) are identical. `$` is an alias for `jQuery`. This is trivially easy to prove to yourself; open up any page that includes jQuery (like this one, Stack Overflow itself), and try `$ == jQuery` on the developer console. Do you have something more substantial than "no they're not" to back up your argument?

Comment: I read that as "`$('#loadForm')` and `document.getElementById('loadForm')` are the same." I guess I spliced comments via dyslexia? Anyhow, yes, `$` is `jQuery` provided there are no collisions.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the leading hash from your argument to `document.getElementById`, as it is not part of the ID:

```
document.getElementById('FormContainer')
```

`document.getElementById('#FormContainer')` returns `null`. And you can't change the property `style` of `null`, because `null` is a primitive value and has no properties.

Or as you are already using jQuery just do:

```
$('#FormContainer').toggle(); // toggles visibility
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using Jquery already, might as well go with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#loadForm').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#FormContainer').show();
    })
});
```